# How to connect to PDB and create tablespace USERS backup in oracle?

Tags: oracle, backup

[image]

I tried to connect. What is my target? sys@orclpdb?

[image]

Comment: Your target is your database. Even if you have a million pdbs, there is still one target. In your scenario, probably it is called 'ORCL'. You can connect to target over SQL Net (TCP) rman target sys/pwd@<TNS_ALIAS> or OS auth (Bequeath) rman target /

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. What is pwd? and What is TNS_ALIAS? Where can I find it?

Comment: Hi, pwd - short for the sys password. TNS_ALIAS is a "tag" for the connect information stored in the file 'tnsnames.ora' located on your disk $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/tnsnames.ora most likely.